# how to get informations about relationship of tables in oracle?

Tags: oracle, foreign-key-relationship

i need to get information about relationship of tables in following format:

```
source_table    source_pk    source_fk    destination_table    destination_pk
............    .........    .........    .................    ..............

 employees     employee_id    job_id            jobs               job_id
```

it says table 'employees' with primary key of 'employee_id' and foreign key of 'job_id' refer to table 'jobs' with primary key of 'job_id'.
is there any query to give me this information?
update:
i want a query that fill this table with all relationships of a particular schema like 'hr'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query any of dba_constraints, all_constraints or user_constraints views based on your access level as follows

```
WITH tab AS (SELECT table_name, 
                    MIN(decode(constraint_type, 'P', constraint_name, NULL)) PRIMARY_KEY, 
                    MIN(decode(constraint_type, 'R', constraint_name, NULL)) FOREIGN_KEY,
                    MIN(decode(constraint_type, 'R', r_constraint_name, NULL)) DESTINATION_PK
               FROM dba_Constraints
              WHERE table_name = 'EMPLOYEE'
              GROUP BY table_name)
SELECT t.table_name, t.PRIMARY_KEY, t.FOREIGN_KEY, uc.table_name, t.DESTINATION_PK
  FROM tab t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dba_Constraints uc 
    ON (uc.constraint_name = t.destination_pk);
```

To get information about all tables in particular schema(example HR):

```
WITH tab AS (SELECT table_name, 
                    MIN(decode(constraint_type, 'P', constraint_name, NULL)) PRIMARY_KEY, 
                    MIN(decode(constraint_type, 'R', constraint_name, NULL)) FOREIGN_KEY,
                    MIN(decode(constraint_type, 'R', r_constraint_name, NULL)) DESTINATION_PK
               FROM all_constraints
              WHERE owner = 'HR'
              GROUP BY table_name)
SELECT t.table_name, t.PRIMARY_KEY, t.FOREIGN_KEY, uc.table_name, t.DESTINATION_PK
  FROM tab t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN all_constraints uc 
    ON (uc.constraint_name = t.destination_pk)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Note: If there are no primary key on a table, no rows will be returned.

Comment: i want this information about all relationship in a particular schema and table employee is just an example.

Comment: In that case replace `WHERE table_name = 'EMPLOYEE'` with schema name

Comment: i tried this query on hr schema but it reply with 'no rows selected'.

Comment: You need to modify the query for schema name, I have updated original post.